# How to create a room with ThreeJS

Tags: javascript

I'm starting to use three.js, and I'm trying to transform a 2D house plan to 3D. Is it possible? Does anybody have an example?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this website. It contain lot more example. Just go through each code and develop yours.

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_cloth

Then come up with your try code, if you face any problem. As of now this info will help you to move forward.